# Yorkshire Dales: Towns to stay in

Tags: accommodation, yorkshire

We would like to stay in the Yorkshire Dales for 2 nights (3 days) and as a quick glance at a map will show, it's a rather large area.  We will have a car but would like to minimize driving.  So if one location makes sense for most stuff with just a few long drives, that would be ideal.  Can someone recommend towns that are close to most of the attractions and pleasant to stay in?  I refrain from asking for specific house/B&B/hotel recommendations as I believe that's against the rules.  However, I don't think asking for towns is unreasonable.

I'm sure the response will be "Depends on what you want to see".  I haven't definitively decided on what to see (I've never been there!), but here are some things I have in mind

1) First and foremost, just pleasant walks through countryside. ~2 hour hikes.

2) Bolton Abby & Bolton Castle

3) Ingelton Falls and/or Caves

4) How Stean Gorge

5) Forbidden Corner (no interest myself, but thought it might be good for kids)

6) Hawes and Wensleydale Creamery (worth doing?)

7) Malham Cove

As you can see, these are all over the Dales.  Any advice?  And although it's off topic, I'd greatly appreciate comments of the form "I can't believe you're thinking of Dales and not considering attraction xxx" or "I wouldn't waste time with number X from your list".

I have done some research.  One town close to Ingleton is: Barnoldswick.  As you can see though, it's to the west of the Dales so places like How Stean Gorge and The Forbidden Corner would be quite far (>1 hour).  Like I said, perhaps the best I can do is get someplace close to most stuff, and resign myself to a few long drives.
Thanks, Dave

Comment: I'm surprised you put this question on hold.  I have now read The WANTA debate.  It states: "designing someone's itinerary around a country when they provide no indication of what they enjoy, want to see, or how they want to travel and so on."   I gave 7 specific things I want to see and ask for recs on suitable towns to stay in. I believe only someone who has visited the area or a local would have insights on the actual state of roads and travel times. The information on this rural area can not be surmised from Google Maps. I also clearly stated that I am travelling by car.